# Recursively tar'ing subfolders of a main folder

Tags: bash

I have a folder, called `webseiten` with different subfolders.

I want those subfolders to be tar'd. Name of those tars should be the name of the subfolder that gets tar'd.

How can I do that?

My guess is:

`find webseiten/ -type d -exec tar -cfvz` - but whats now? How to pass the desired output name to exec?

As it seems to be a little odd what I want to achieve:

I don't want one big Tar with all subfolders in it.
I want a tar for each subfolder in my main folder.

So basically:

Content of `webseiten`:

- folder-1
- folder-2
- folder-3
- folder-4

Then the output should be `folder-1.tar.gz`, `folder-2.tar.gz`, `folder-3.tar.gz` and `folder-4.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd webseiten
for dir in */
do
    tar -czf "$(basename "$dir").tar.gz" "$dir"
done
```

That is literally it. For more information, `man tar` (and `man find`).

Comment: Thats not what I want, sorry l0b0. I'll specify it a little more, give me a second.

Comment: Gonna check your script in a second and give you a quick feedback.